# how to extract value of a <td> when you only know the <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML, which is generated dynamically for me via a jQuery plug in:

```
<tr class="even selected" role="row" id="row_231">
<td>231</td>
<td class="sorting_1">John Doe</td>
<td>23819</td>
<td>test@yahoo.com</td>
</tr>
```

the only piece of information I have is the id on the `<TR>`.
This is the jQuery code I have that, among other things, captures the tr that the user has selected:

```
var selected = [];

$('#users tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
    if ( index === -1 ) {
        selected.push( id );
    } else {
        selected.splice( index, 1 );
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );
```

This logic works well - it highlights and tracks what has been selected.  Now what I need to do is display inside a div on the same page, the contents of the 2nd and 4th columns for each row that is selected. So using the sample HTML above, I want to show something like this:

```
  John Doe - test@yahoo.com
```

Comment: `$( "tr" ).find( "td" )`

Comment: `this.cells[1]` and `this.cells[3]` will give you the second and fourth `td` elements inside the clicked row. Much lighter and faster than using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the div you want to populate is has an ID of "results" and the table cells always stay in the same order you can use [.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [.eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get those values and then append them to the results div:

```js
var selected = [];

$('#users tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
        if ( index === -1 ) {
            selected.push( id );
        } else {
            selected.splice( index, 1 );
        }
    
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        // Find td's inside this tr and get the values from the 2nd and 4th ones
        var tds = $(this).find('td');
        $('#results').append(tds.eq(1).text() + " - " + tds.eq(3).text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="users">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even selected" role="row" id="row_231">
      <td>231</td>
      <td class="sorting_1">John Doe</td>
      <td>23819</td>
      <td>test@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br /><br />
Results
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the positions are always number 2 and 4, you can use eq(i), for example:

```
$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() //John Doe
$(this).find('td:eq(3)').text() //test@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If this value appears always on 2nd and 4th `td` then you can use the following code:

```
var name = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
var email = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text();
```

Alternative solution with same result:

```
var name = $("td:nth-child(2)", this).text();
var email = $("td:nth-child(4)", this).text();
```

**References**

[:eq() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

[:nth-child() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

This simple example will show you how to do it:

```js
$().ready(function(){
  $('#Div1').html($('#TR1 :nth-child(1)').html() + ' ' + $('#TR1 :nth-child(3)').html() )
})
```

```css
#Div1 {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='TR1'>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id='Div1'></div>
```